# How remove margin in a paragraph that continues in two pages with different margin?

Tags: margins, double-sided

I've created a document whose margins have different odd and even pages. I want to write a paragraph with no margin in two pages runs. If I use the command `\newgeometry`  new paragraph starts at the top of new page, that I want to start at the same place. And the command `\begin{adjustwidth}{}{}` such marginalized different odd and even pages are not useful. Please guide me in this regard.

I use this command for create margin:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} 
‎‎\usepackage[total={215mm,285mm}‎,‎top=3cm,bottom=3cm,headsep=10pt,
    vmargin=2cm,
    outermargin=7cm,
    innermargin=2.5cm,
    marginparwidth=5cm,
    marginparsep=10pt]{geometry}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't understand the question. Please _always_ include a complete small document that shows the problem, edit the question to be a complete example and show what output you get, and describe what you want to get.

Comment: Your specifications are incoherent: setting `vmargin=2cm` makes `top=2cm` *and* `bottom=2cm`, which contradicts the previous values. What paper format do you use that lets you set `width=215mm`? It is larger than a4paper width.

Comment: If can create a command like
\begin{nomargin}

\end{nomargin}
That it works in a couple of pages :
\begin{adjustwidth}{-5cm}{}

\end{adjustwidth}
And the individual pages to be :
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-5cm}

\end{adjustwidth}
?

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand the question, but here is one way to change the horizontal margins of one (or several) paragraphs midtext.

Please be aware, that the paper has to be bigger than the type block.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} 
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=260mm,%%The paper must be bigger than the body
    paperheight=330mm,
total={215mm,285mm},
%top=3cm,
%bottom=3cm,
%%headsep=10pt,
%%%vmargin=2cm,
%outermargin=7cm,
showframe,
%innermargin=2.5cm,
%marginparwidth=5cm,
%marginparsep=10pt
]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{addmargin}{-1cm}
    \blindtext
\end{addmargin}

\begin{addmargin}[2cm]{-1cm}
    \blindtext
\end{addmargin}
\clearpage
\blindtext

\begin{addmargin}{-1cm}
    \blindtext
\end{addmargin}

\begin{addmargin*}[2cm]{-1cm}
    \blindtext

    \blindtext
\end{addmargin*}
\end{document}
```