# Geometry package: Lengths saved by default. Options for save/load/restore

Tags: margins, geometry, paper-size, lengths

**The `geometry` package**:

Package lengths are not saved as lengths.

- Examples: `layoutheight, tmargin`

The following only affect the complete layout:

- `\savegeometry`
- `\loadgeometry`
- `\restoregeometry`

**Question 1**

Is it possible to set the package such that
lengths which are not native to Latex may be called?

- Examples: `\layoutheight, \tmargin`

**Question 2**

Is it possible to elegantly save/load/restore specific geometry options only?
Similar to `\newgeometry{<options>}`?

- `\savegeometry[<options>]{name}`
- `\loadgeometry[<options>]{name}`
- `\restoregeometry[<options>]`

**Alternative**: [`\newlength` --> `setlength` Method]

A method exists which creates the lengths **and** uses them recursively.
I demonstrate this below in the MWE.

It is not entirely elegant.

I wish I could, in the preamble:

```
\savegeometry{original}
% or
\savegeometry[vmargin, hmargin]{originalMargins}
```

Then, after changing the page size mid-document,

```
\loadgeometry[vmargin, hmargin]{original}
% or
\loadgeometry{originalMargins}
% or especially (without the need to \save):
\restoregeometry[vmargin, hmargin]
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}                   % margin/page layout settings
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}           % improved header commands. [supercedes `fancyhdr' package].
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Margin Settings:
\newlength{\xhmargin   } \setlength{\xhmargin   }{0.750in}
\newlength{\xtmargin   } \setlength{\xtmargin   }{0.750in}
\newlength{\xbmargin   } \setlength{\xbmargin   }{1.000in}
\newlength{\xheadheight} \setlength{\xheadheight}{2.700em}
\newlength{\xheadsep   } \setlength{\xheadsep   }{0.150in}
\newlength{\xfootheight} \setlength{\xfootheight}{2.700em}
\newlength{\xfootskip  } \setlength{\xfootskip  }{0.800in}

\KOMAoptions{headheight = \xheadheight , 
             footheight = \xfootheight , 
             DIV        = current      }

\geometry{letterpaper                ,
          hmargin      = \xhmargin   ,
          tmargin      = \xtmargin   ,
          bmargin      = \xbmargin   ,
          headsep      = \xheadsep   ,
          footskip     = \xfootskip  }
%\usepackage{showframe}
\savegeometry{default}




%Initialize headers and footers
\chead{\normalfont Header 1 \\ Header 2}
\cfoot{\normalfont Footer 1 \\ Footer 2}
\ofoot{\normalfont Page \thepage}


\begin{document}
Original

\lipsum


\clearpage




%\pdfpagewidth  = 11.0in     % [\pdfpagewidth and \pdfpageheight are superceded by KOMAoptions].
%\pdfpageheight = 17.0in
\KOMAoptions{paper      = 11in:17in    ,
             pagesize                  ,
             headheight = \xheadheight , 
             footheight = \xfootheight , 
             DIV        = current      }
%\restoregeometry            % [cannot be used: restores letterpaper also.]
\newgeometry{layoutwidth  = 11.00in,
             layoutheight = 17.00in, 
             hmargin      = \xhmargin   ,
             tmargin      = \xtmargin   ,
             bmargin      = \xbmargin   ,
             headsep      = \xheadsep   ,
             footskip     = \xfootskip  }

Altered

\lipsum

\vspace{+4em}

\lipsum




\clearpage




%\pdfpagewidth  = 08.5in     % [\pdfpagewidth and \pdfpageheight are superceded by KOMAoptions].
%\pdfpageheight = 11.0in
\KOMAoptions{paper = 8.5in:11in,
             pagesize          ,
             DIV=current       }
\restoregeometry

Original

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\paperwidth` is standard.... `geometry` doesn't support changing the paper size mid-document. Does KOMA support this? Note that mixing KOMA config with `geometry` like this is asking for trouble really. You can ignore KOMA's config and use `geometry`, but mixing them seems like a recipe for problems....

Comment: Oop.  I'll edit the paperwidth out.  As for the KOMA, MScharrer is all about it.  He posts this solution everywhere: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document @MartinScharrer.

Comment: KOMA aside, I put the alternative in, to keep this geometry focused : j [Unless you know of a method to set custom margins in KOMA - despite every attempt KOMA is making to get me to use its default margins.]

Comment: I am interested in the background, why do you want to do this? Maybe [How remove margin in a paragraph that continues in two pages with different margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214254) and [Italic or font change for a whole section](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251024) can be of help for your use case?

Comment: I don't advice you to use this unless you know (deeply) what you  do.

Comment: @Johannes_B : Currently, altering the page size mid-document can be accomplished with `\pdfpagewidth` (and `height`) or `\KOMAoptions`.  If one is using DIV-style margins, he or she is good to go with `DIV=current`.  If one is using `geometry` to set specific margins (please, hold your fire), he or she must reset the layout and the margins manually.  This is inelegant, as layout lengths should have the option of easily being set to the current paper size lengths, and margin lengths should have the option of easily being set to the previous margin lengths (including the header/footer lengths).

Comment: @Johannes_B :  An additional issue with manual settings is that, should the user change the default margins later, each of the manual settings must be discovered and altered also, if consistency is desired.